# Spring MVC: Open link in new browser window in handler method

Tags: spring-mvc

I have a controller that handle clicking on links. In handler method i have to do something (on db) and open clicked url in new window (something like **_blank** attribute in links). I use "redirect:url", but it redirect of course in the same window. Any ideas ?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/open.html")
public String open(@RequestParam(value="id") Integer id) {
    Link link = linkDAO.get(id);
    linkDAO.click(id);
    return "redirect:"+link.getAddress();
}
```

Comment: This is not something the server can tell a client to do. You need to write the corresponding JavaScript code in your View / JSP.

Comment: Thanks, You right. I do not know what came over me... ;) I did as You said with ajax: `jQuery.get('open.html?id='+id, function(data) { window.open(url); });`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved this using JavaScript and AJAX - as @Patrick suggest. Maybe it will be helpful for someone.

```
<a href="#" onclick="openLink(${link.id},'${link.address}');">Open</a>
```

`openLink` function:

```
function openLink(id, url) {
    jQuery.get('open.html?id='+id, function(data) { 
      if(data == 'OK') {
        window.open(url);
      } 
    }, 'text');
}
```

Handler method:

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/open.html")
public String open(@RequestParam(value="id") Integer id) {
    Link link = linkDAO.get(id);
    linkDAO.click(id);
    return "OK";
}
```