# return new ModelAndView("redirect:bpView.do?lang=en") in page like window.open

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

`return new ModelAndView("redirect:bpView.do?lang=en")` like `window.open`.

Hi instead of redirecting , I wish to open it in a new page(like `window.open()` in Javascript) . How can this be done?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Spring MVC: Open link in new browser window in handler method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5377459/spring-mvc-open-link-in-new-browser-window-in-handler-method)

Answer (score 0):

[Spring MVC: Open link in new browser window in handler method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5377459/spring-mvc-open-link-in-new-browser-window-in-handler-method)

Says there, it can't be done server side. I also don't remember reading about anything like that in the spring documentation.